# smb running but not appearing in network

Tags: fedora, smb

So i'm trying to setup a few shares on my home network and after 2 days of googleing i can't get it to work.
i've added it to firewalld, but all i see is it being unhappy about printers.
Both the PC and the Server are on Fedora 21.

Thanks Rob

```
[root@localhost samba]# systemctl status smb -l
    ● smb.service - Samba SMB Daemon
       Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/smb.service; enabled)
       Active: active (running) since Sat 2014-12-27 12:07:01 GMT; 32min ago
     Main PID: 10308 (smbd)
       Status: "smbd: ready to serve connections..."
       CGroup: /system.slice/smb.service
               ├─10308 /usr/sbin/smbd
               └─10309 /usr/sbin/smbd

    Dec 27 12:07:01 localhost.localdomain smbd[10309]: STATUS=daemon 'smbd' finished starting up and ready to serve connectionsfailed to retrieve printer list: NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL

    Dec 27 12:08:01 localhost.localdomain smbd[10314]: [2014/12/27 12:08:01.788537,  0]../source3/printing/print_cups.c:151(cups_connect)

    Dec 27 12:08:01 localhost.localdomain smbd[10309]: [2014/12/27 12:08:01.788826,  0] ../source3/printing/print_cups.c:528(cups_async_callback)

    Dec 27 12:08:01 localhost.localdomain smbd[10309]: failed to retrieve printer list: NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL

    Dec 27 12:21:02 localhost.localdomain smbd[10550]: [2014/12/27 12:21:02.537410,  0] ../source3/printing/print_cups.c:151(cups_connect)

    Dec 27 12:21:02 localhost.localdomain smbd[10309]: [2014/12/27 12:21:02.537767,  0] ../source3/printing/print_cups.c:528(cups_async_callback)

    Dec 27 12:21:02 localhost.localdomain smbd[10309]: failed to retrieve printer list: NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL

    Dec 27 12:34:03 localhost.localdomain smbd[10713]: [2014/12/27 12:34:03.319755,  0] ../source3/printing/print_cups.c:151(cups_connect)

    Dec 27 12:34:03 localhost.localdomain smbd[10309]: [2014/12/27 12:34:03.320213,  0] ../source3/printing/print_cups.c:528(cups_async_callback)

    Dec 27 12:34:03 localhost.localdomain smbd[10309]: failed to retrieve printer list: NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL
```

_

```
[root@localhost samba]# testparm
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
Processing section "[Music]"
Processing section "[Films]"
Processing section "[HLI]"
Loaded services file OK.
Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE
Press enter to see a dump of your service definitions
[global]
    workgroup = MYGROUP
    interfaces = lo, eth0
    map to guest = Bad User
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    max log size = 1024
    unix extensions = No
    socket options = TCP_NODELAY SO_RCVBUF=131072 SO_SNDBUF=131072
    load printers = No
    idmap config * : backend = tdb
    hosts allow = 127., 134.173.
    aio read size = 16384
    aio write size = 16384
    use sendfile = Yes
    map hidden = Yes
    map system = Yes
    store dos attributes = Yes
[Music]
    comment = music magic blah blah
    path = /share/music
    valid users = user, root
    read only = No
    guest ok = Yes
[Films]
    comment = moving pics!
    path = /share/films
    valid users = user, root
    read only = No
    guest ok = Yes
[HLI]
    comment = HLI Files Here
    path = /share/HLI
    valid users = user, root
    read only = No
    guest ok = Yes
```

_

```
[root@localhost ~]# netstat --inet --inet6 -lnp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1184/perl           
tcp        0      0 192.168.122.1:53        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1170/dnsmasq        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1109/sshd           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:445             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1131/smbd           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:139             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1131/smbd           
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1109/sshd           
tcp6       0      0 :::445                  :::*                    LISTEN      1131/smbd           
tcp6       0      0 :::9090                 :::*                    LISTEN      1/systemd           
tcp6       0      0 :::139                  :::*                    LISTEN      1131/smbd           
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21246           0.0.0.0:*                           1075/dhclient       
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10000           0.0.0.0:*                           1184/perl           
udp        0      0 192.168.122.1:53        0.0.0.0:*                           1170/dnsmasq        
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:67              0.0.0.0:*                           1170/dnsmasq        
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           1075/dhclient       
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:123             0.0.0.0:*                           681/chronyd         
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:323           0.0.0.0:*                           681/chronyd         
udp6       0      0 :::123                  :::*                                681/chronyd         
udp6       0      0 :::16665                :::*                                1075/dhclient       
udp6       0      0 ::1:323                 :::*                                681/chronyd         
raw6       0      0 :::58                   :::*                    7           753/NetworkManager
```

_

```
[root@localhost ~]# tcpdump -i eth0 -n \( tcp port 139 or tcp port 445 \) and host 192.168.1.111
tcpdump: eth0: No such device exists
(SIOCGIFHWADDR: No such device)
```

Comment: What does "can't get it to work" mean exactly? What is the output of `netstat --inet --inet6 -lnp`? What is the output of `tcpdump -i eth0 -n \( tcp port 139 or tcp port 445 \) and host 1.2.3.4` (with your IP address, of course) while you try to access the server? Is a firewall running on that system? Does it work if you deactivate it?

Comment: As in when i go to Browse Network nothing appears, firewalld was running but now isnt and ive seen no change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that `nmbd` is not running. If it was then `netstat` would print a line like this:

```
udp   0   0 0.0.0.0:137   0.0.0.0:*   4691/nmbd
```

Without `nmbd` the system is not seen on the network. But it should be possible to connect to it. It seems that `192.168.122.1` is your LAN IP address. Enter this address in a SMB browser. On a Windows client you would enter `\\192.168.122.1` in Windows Explorer. Linux clients may need something like `smb://192.168.122.1`.

In a shell you could do this:

```
smbclient -I 192.168.122.1 -L //foo -U yourusername
smbclient -I 192.168.122.1 //foo/sharename -U yourusername
```

Furthermore your LAN interface name is not `eth0` thus it doesn't make sense to put in in `smb.conf` (`interfaces = lo, eth0`). Of course, when checking with `tcpdump` you should have used the correct name, too. `ip addr` shows you the interface names and addresses.

It may be necessary to allow NetBIOS broadcasts in your firewall.